# Why CloudKit notification doesn't arrive when app is installed from testflight while it works when compiled from Xcode?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, sharing

CloudKit notifications doesn't arrive on production (AppStore, TestFlight), but works in development mode (installed from Xcode).

Why?

This is how I register for remote notifications:

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { authorised, error in
        
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
```

and this is how I save subscriptions:

```
func subscribeForChanges() {
    
    let options: CKQuerySubscriptionOptions = [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion]
    
    let serviceSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Service", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let goalSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Goal", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let territorySubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Territory", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let addressSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Address", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let noteSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Note", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let daySubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Day", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    let shareSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "cloudkit.share", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    
    let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    
    serviceSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    goalSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    territorySubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    addressSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    noteSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    daySubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    shareSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
    
    let privateSubscriptionsOperation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [serviceSubscription, goalSubscription, territorySubscription, addressSubscription, noteSubscription, daySubscription, shareSubscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
    privateSubscriptionsOperation.database = CloudAssistant.shared.privateDatabase
    
    let notificationInfoDatabaseSubscription = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfoDatabaseSubscription.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    
    let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "pl.blue-world.fieldservice.sharedDatabase")
    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfoDatabaseSubscription
    let sharedSubscriptionsOperation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
    sharedSubscriptionsOperation.database = CloudAssistant.shared.sharedDatabase

    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    queue.addOperation(privateSubscriptionsOperation)
    queue.addOperation(sharedSubscriptionsOperation)
    privateDatabase.save(CKRecordZone(zoneName: "fieldservice")) { _, _ in }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CloudKit, but if I remember correctly the APNS (may work the same way), you'd have one Certificate for the Production and another for the Development. I'd guess that the TestFlight use the Distribution and the XCode one use the dev one. So on XCode when you put your app on your device, change the Scheme, do not use "Debug".

Comment: I do not use nay certificates for even development mode;) No APNS certificates at all, and... it works for app installed from zcode. Why?

Comment: It does actually (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1917/_index.html, but that could be "internally"), but I'm not sure that's your issue, I was just guessing and trying to help your find maybe an hint.

Comment: no, it is not the case, it was working before. I thing the case is somewhere else;) Before it was working because it was for ios 9 also, now I abandoned ios 9 and support the app only for ios 10 and 11... registering for push notifications is a little bit different there. Maybe this is the case... I will check it

Comment: If you revert back to an xcode build, do the notifs start again?

Comment: @Thunk yes, it works then...

Answer (score 1):

When something similar happened to me, it was caused by mixing up the server change tokens between the dev and prod environments. In my case, the dev change token was, say aaabbb, while the prod change token was something earlier, like, aaaaab. Since I was inadvertently using the dev change token, it was "ahead" of prod.

I see you've edited your question, but as I recall from the prior version, I believe you have already configured xcode builds to use the prod env. But, there's a simple test to prove or disprove if this theory is related to your problem. After you app inits in the env where you are not receiving notifs, call

CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation

Using Nil for the server change token. That should return every notif since the very start for that user. If the results include the missing notifs, then the problem is probably in the way you're handling change tokens.

Otherwise, I would dump all subs for that user using

CKFetchSubscriptionOperation

on both an xcode build and a testflight build, and compare the two sets, paying close attention to the predicates. I would expect the lists to be identical since you were already using the prod env, but I would rule this simple test out before looking for more complicated causes.

Answer (score 0):

Silent push notifications are problematic in iOS 11.0.X In iOS 11.1 there was a fix.

In development mode you might get the notification because generally the device is connected by the power cable to you computer. Silent notifications are processed when connected to power!

If your development device is iOS 11.0.X this might be the issue.

Comment: Sounds interestin, but my device is 11.2. I enabled Background Modes in Capabilities... and it works. Why?

Comment: Then must be the using the equivalent of application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler. To give it a slot of time to handle the sync.